# Firefox redirecting to other webpages and Adobe Flash Player plugin update button redirects to other webpage (not the adobe offical page)

Tags: malware, web-browser, firewalls, firefox, safe-browsing-filter

When I try to update the Adobe Flash Player plugin for Firefox by clicking on the button for updating the plugin, it redirects to itsmyviews.com. In addition, when I visit the any site, my browser transfers data from nexac.com, itsmyviews.com and many other sites which I can not read because they are changing quickly. It also attempts to connect to bh.contextweb.com, s7.addthis.com and many other sites. When I visit the any webpage an advertisement covers the whole windows when I try to close that ad then that tab of the browser automatically disappear.
Screen Shot of my PC.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3EPe.png

Comment: You have a browser redirect infection. Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal forum.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating flash via adobe flash update application(not firefox) Link: https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/ as for the redirect issues try creating a new user profile sounds like u got some malware https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/profileswitcher/

If making a new user profile does not work i suggest installing anti-malware bytes if your running windows and running a scan.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: adobe flash Player offical site is not accessible. When i try to access it will redirect me to  itsmyviews.com

Comment: When i Try to access the adobe official website it redirects me to itsmyviews.com. The same issue is with in the other browse except Microsoft edge.  I reset the firefox but issue still persist.

Comment: I would check dns settings on your system and router if your router has default credentials set. Are you using windows?

Comment: ok scrap the dns stuff if Microsoft edge works. Does your system have powershell? What version os microsoft windows are you running?

Comment: I have created two vbs scripts. Copy the code into notepad and save as vbs script and the run the script as administrator. You should then soon see a file called "install_flash_player.exe" under c:\ There are two links(scripts) use the one that suites your operating system. http://pastebin.com/RFQgzmwb http://pastebin.com/EZGsmza1 (download is approx 19mb)